# Why do base_convert, dechex and decbin return unpadded strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, ordinals

Okay, so I understand that in the world of PHP—and this level of programming in general—ordinal values rule. So a number like `18` would simply be returned as `18` when generated in a PHP function. That makes sense to me. Base 10 numbers typically do not get left `0` padding by default.

But then comes along [`base_convert`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php), [`dechex`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) & [`decbin`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php). Which each have the following format where a string is returned:

> **string** base_convert ( **string** $number , **int** $frombase , **int** $tobase )
>
> **string** dechex ( **int** $number )
>
> **string** decbin ( **int** $number )

Which makes sense because values like these are not ordinal numbers in PHP:

> **ord** `13` becomes **hex** `d`
>
> **ord** `32` becomes **bin** `100000`

Now these are technically correct values. But what doesn’t make sense to me is why each of the returned values doesn’t have left padding like this which seems to be more human readable to me:

> **ord** `13` becomes **hex** `0d`
>
> **ord** `32` becomes **bin** `00100000`

Is there some logical reason I am missing as to why there isn’t a left `0` padding option for binary & hex numbers generated via [`base_convert`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php), [`dechex`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php) & [`decbin`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php)?

It seems to me a simple padding option could be added to the interface of each function? Possibly as simple as a `true`/`false` with perhaps options similar to [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php). Or was such an option purposely left off due to the potential formatting rabbit hole of complexity adding such options would create? Meaning, “Just use `str_pad` since these are strings & not ordinal numbers so do with it as you wish.”

Comment: Because they didn't think of it (which seems to be a very common reason in PHP...).

Comment: For what it's worth, Javascript's `Number#toString` doesn't left-pad its results either. Tacking string-padding on to such a function feels somewhat orthogonal to its purpose, IMO. If you keep going that way, you will reach [`gzgetss`](http://us.php.net/gzgetss)...

Comment: Maybe because that if you were to use those as variables, that PHP would treat a leading zero as an octal(?)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Except that PHP interprets all strings used in a numeric context as decimal.

Comment: Kind of a "catch-22" then @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams